# Stop WCF From Adding A Signature To The SOAP Header

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have placed `ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None` on the `ServiceContract` for my WCF client (which calls a SOAP service), but WCF is still adding a signature to the header.

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "IMyOutboundService", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
```

How do I switch off the header signature for this client?

I am using a `customBinding` with `authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"` and I have set `<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"/>`. I can use a different binding, as long as allows this.

Here is the current binding in full:

```
    <binding name="MyBinding" openTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10" >
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
                includeTimestamp="true"
                enableUnsecuredResponse="true">
        <localClientSettings timestampValidityDuration="00:15:00"/>
      </security>
      <httpsTransport
        manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="true" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="5242880"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered"  unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="true"  />
    </binding>
```

Comment: So far, my research suggests that you can't switch off the signature if you are using "MutualCertificate" authentication mode... so confirmation or evidence of this would be useful too if anyone knows whether this is true!

Comment: can you have a SOAP Listener and intercept the message and remove the header physically ?

Comment: i meant signature from the header

Comment: From recollection - pertty sure you MUST sign the header if you use mutualcert...otherwise I *think* you would be saying "my message is signed/encrypted and so is verifiable, my header isn't signed so don't trust it...therefore don't trust it's message"

Comment: @BlueChippy as far as I can tell there isn't an authentication mode that does client and server transport only certificates - is that the case?

Comment: hmm...I'll have to check that...can't think of one of the top of my head...

Comment: I think you could do that with a basicHttpBinding - or perhaps with a MessageContract http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx and put ProtectionLevel.None in the [MessageHeader] attribute.

Comment: @BlueChippy thanks for your help on this - I think I have it fixed now, but this was all very painful and it helps when people share the pain - so thank you.

Comment: "...you must award this bounty as soon as possible" - ha ha ha! Award it where? There are no valid answers - only my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this one working, the hard way!

```
    <binding name="MyBinding" openTimeout="00:00:10" sendTimeout="00:00:10" >
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
      <httpsTransport
        manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="true" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="5242880"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered"  unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="true"  />
    </binding>
```

So by keeping a custom binding, rather than switching to a basic binding (which I did try) you can keep the Soap11WSAddressing10 (i.e. you get all your SOAP headers).

By removing the `<security` element, you essentially set things to transport-only security. In transport-only mode, no signatures are added.

Sadly, the one thing missing is the timestamp. I cannot find a configuration that will add a timestamp - so I am having to add this manually. This is trivial compared to getting all this other stuff working, so to be honest I'm delighted to do it.